# Did the United States spend $118,000 to study if a metal replica of Thanos could snap his fingers?

Tags: united-states, politics

According to this video, [Rand Paul states the United States spent $118,000 USD to see if a metal replica of Thanos could snap his fingers](https://youtu.be/cNujSc12Bjw?t=120). Is this what they were trying to figure out with these funds?

> We spent $118,000 to study if a metal replica, a robot, of Marvel Comics evil warlord Thanos could snap his fingers. [...] They apparently hired some dude to wear metal gloves and then try to snap his fingers. You know what? They found out it's impossible to make a snapping sound with metal fingers. So robots of the world, be warned: it's hard to snap your fingers.

Comment: Dear Hot Network Question visitors: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Please read the link before answering or commenting.

Comment: Rand Paul's people who are trying to channel the spirit of William Proxmire did not do a thorough job. They missed the $994k grant to Georgia Tech for [Fast, Furious and Fantastic Beasts](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1941933&HistoricalAwards=false), which also funded some of this research.

Comment: Um, actually, the word "replica" means "exact duplicate". Since Thanos was not made out of metal, any metal copy of Thanos would not be a "replica".

Comment: To whom with relevant interest, let alone knowledge could a minxy little $118,000 matter, in the quest for a metal replica of Thanos snapping his fingers?

Comment: This kind of thing is always frustrating to me as a researcher - You're criticised because the public can't understand your research, but when you try and link it to a pop culture thing, in the spirit of fun and to make it engaging, someone comes along in bad faith and says it's a waste of money. The best similar example is probably the research that shows why spaghetti breaks into three pieces when you snap it - it's important in basically everything that has similar failure modes, like, say, suspension bridge cables.

Comment: @lupe We have the same problem everywhere. Just society doesn't get to fall back to kid-mode and justify expenses with kid-culture or kid talk. For example, if it turns out 95% of cell phone water-failure is because people drop their phones in the toilet, I probably don't want sell the solution to my boss, or a consumer as "toilet-protection" but instead "ip67 water resistant", etc. Which basically amounts to one meter of fresh water, or as a layman knows it: "all the way in the toilet" protection. 1/5 people drop their phone in the toilet.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: [Of](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/12/07/elon-musk-ceo-is-made-up-title-prefers-tesla-technoking.html) [course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk's_Tesla_Roadster) [people](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2022-10-31/musk-takes-chief-twit-title-at-twitter-video) [could](https://www.businessinsider.com/elon-musk-boring-company-started-as-joke-la-tunnels-may-fail-2018-9) [kid-mode](https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/trends/exa-dark-siderael-musk-aka-y-what-elon-musk-grimes-new-babys-name-means-8221371.html).  [It's a power move.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dad_joke)

Answer (score 56):

The grant is [#2019371](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=2019371&HistoricalAwards=false), where the $118k+ is only the 2020 funds. From the description, it seems clear that they published a paper and are planning another that builds on the first. [That first paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2021.0672) is open access; a snippet reads:

> Using high-speed imaging and force sensors, we analyse the dynamics of the finger snap… Our analysis reveals the central role of skin friction in mediating the snap dynamics by acting as a latch to control the resulting high velocities and accelerations. We evaluate the role of this frictional latch experimentally, by covering the thumb and middle finger with different materials to produce different friction coefficients and varying compressibility… We also develop a soft, compressible friction-based latch-mediated spring actuated model to further elucidate the key role of friction and how it interacts with a compressible latch.

They did not test a "metal glove". The closest test was of thimbles under medical gloves:

> Force data are collected for 5 snaps made while wearing a nitrile glove with lubrication, while wearing latex rubber on both fingers, and while wearing a metal thimble on both fingers underneath the nitrile glove.

It seems "hired some dude" does not seem to be an accurate description either:

> We thank two members of the BhamlaLab for volunteering to participate in the finger snap experiments.

[Thanos was an inspiration](https://www.nsf.gov/news/mmg/mmg_disp.jsp?med_id=187859&from=) for the work, but it's not about him. The authors suggest that the research will be helpful in understanding the mechanics behind creatures like [termites](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UrZdN8x-XkI) and [ants](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/13/science/dracula-ants-jaws-fastest.html) which have snapping mandibles, in addition to being useful for developing prosthetics and "[soft robotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_robotics)".

Comment: Any ideas why the NSF site sometimes uses £ instead of $? I assume it is some sort of bug, not a reference to English pounds.

Comment: @Oddthinking I've only seen them use $. I wonder if it's trying to translate the amount for you, even though you don't use pounds.

Comment: I don't understand how snapping human fingers covered with different materials can illuminate how ant mandibles work. Maybe that's better answered on one of the science sites.

Comment: Since the claim so strongly mentions Thanos, can you explain how the work was "inspired" by Thanos? Edit: looks like it's in the other answer.

Comment: Now that I've read DavePhD's answer, I must say that you pretty quickly gloss over how much they *do* talk about Thanos, while also glossing over any real use this study might produce in the future. Rand's point is clearly one against frivolous spending, so these details matter.

Comment: @fredsbend From the paper: "Multiple termite species, including Termes panamaensis and Pericapritermes nitobei, as well as a species of ant known as Mystrium camillae, have all been observed pressing their mandibles together to generate ultrafast motion in a manner reminiscent of the finger snap that humans perform".

Comment: @Laurel Yes, we already understand that. How does metal gloves explain it?

Comment: @fredsbend I don't understand the criticism. They're comparing several different types of materials with varying friction coefficients, one of which involves metal thimbles under rubber gloves. They collected the data to compare to the other materials. Several of the authors have papers on the subject of fast moving parts of various insects, so I'd expect them to be publishing something in the future that explores that angle in depth.

Comment: For the record: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/t9nHIvm) of the NSF site using a pound symbol. My browser probably tells it I am from Australia - we don't use pounds here.

Comment: @fredsbend: I searched the paper for Thanos and found zero direct references. There was a mention of Avenger movies (which weren't included in the reference section! For shame!) In their press release, they mention Thanos, presumably to attract attention. I am not sure if you are asking the OP to explicitly *downplay* the link to Thanos.

Comment: @Oddthinking fwiw: for me (Germany), it is displayed as a generic currency symbol (¤) with otherwise the same numbers. Probably some website error.

Comment: @Oddthinking I'm trying to be sure that relevant details aren't omitted. I'm not asking for anything to be downplayed, but the opposite. With your find and a closer look at Dave's answer, it seems most of the Thanos/Avengers mentions are in press releases, which is a relevant item, I think, since that plausibly explains it being mentioned at all. To attract attention to pop science. However, I'm still struggling to see this ostensible connection to bug mandibles, but as already mentioned, maybe that's a question for a science site.

Comment: @fredsbend The particular insect species mentioned perform a fairly distinctive motion: they put their mandibles together then "snap", ending with them being crossed. It even looks similar to a person snapping their fingers. I linked some videos above.

Comment: @Oddthinking Regarding why you are seeing the pound symbol: I checked the page source; it uses plain old ASCII 0x24 (not even unicode); this is the US dollar symbol. The page source also specifies CSS style tabletext2, which in turn specifies to use the Verdana font. It might be your browser, it might be your computer's implementation of the Verdana font, it might be your settings, or it might be something else. Regardless, the source uses plain old ASCII 0x24.

Answer (score 48):

**The statement is extremely misleading.**

When you say something like “Group of people X paid amount Y to achieve goal Z”, that implies the following things:

1. Achieving goal Z was the primary purpose of spending that money.
2. All of the money Y went towards achieving that goal Z.

These implications are **false** in the current case. What is actually true is:

1. “We” (the US government) did spend $118K in fiscal year 2020 to fund a [research grant](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=2019371&HistoricalAwards=false).
2. *One* of the goals of the grant was to obtain new knowledge about “latch-mediated spring actuation”, a class of mechanical systems seen in nature that contains finger snapping as *one* example.
3. The [sole scientific publication](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2021.0672) resulting from the grant so far did study the mechanics of finger snapping, and did study the question of whether metal fingers could be snapped, and did indirectly refer to the Marvel movies’ Thanos character snapping his fingers. And presumably the researchers did hire someone (whether a “dude” or not, I can’t say) to help perform experiments.

The implications above are false, because studying whether Thanos can snap his fingers was obviously not the stated goal of the researchers — the insight that Thanos would find it more difficult than a human to snap his fingers is only one (completely insignificant) *byproduct* of the work, which Paul conveniently focuses his attention on.

(In fairness to Mr Paul, one of the researchers seems to have played a part in his university issuing a press release hyping this completely insignificant connection to Marvel movies, as discussed in another answer. So arguably the researchers can be seen as guilty of a similar kind of dishonesty as the senator, and in their unnecessary focus on PR probably exposed themselves to the kind of criticism he is leveling at them.)

Moreover, even if the improved understanding of finger snapping was really the only tangible deliverable resulting from the money spent on the grant, scientific research produces many intangible deliverables (training of future scientists, and producing knowledge that may take a few years to get published, and seeding the insights of future, potentially groundbreaking, research, etc) that are difficult to quantify, especially by politicians who seem to care more about creating an impression favorable to their agenda than about getting at the truth. For all we know, that $118K could result in another publication next year that will win the researchers a Nobel prize.

Comment: This answer feels heavily biased and mostly theoretical.

Comment: @fredsbend it’s unclear to me what you mean. Can you point to a specific part of my answer that you find problematic?

Comment: @fredsbend I made some edits, maybe you’d find the answer more balanced now. But in any case if you have specific criticism of anything I wrote, I’d be happy to hear it.

Comment: Latch-mediated spring actuation would have huge implications in switch design, where it's all about pulling the contacts apart *abruptly* to prevent arcing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrMiqEkSk48

Comment: Locked to prevent ongoing edit war. Let's resolve in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141593/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-romik-did-the-united-states-spend-118-000-to-study).

Comment: The part I mostly objected to is now gone. I think it's fair to criticize the researches seeking attention in this way, *"in their unnecessary focus on PR probably exposed themselves to the kind of criticism he is leveling at them."* For me, it's a lot more interesting how ant mandibles might help us produce different materials and products, but I was blindsided with some BS about Thanos. The real use and value to society and science should be the attention seeker, not some strained pop culture reference.

Comment: Note to readers: a part of my answer was removed by the moderators. I consider that an essential part of the answer and objected to the removal, but the moderators have the final say, so there it is. See the [discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141593/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-romik-did-the-united-states-spend-118-000-to-study), and see the answer's [edit history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/54181/revisions) for the part that was removed.

Answer (score 8):

The US National Science Foundation on their official US government website has an article [Snap! A record-breaking motion at our fingertips](https://beta.nsf.gov/news/snap-record-breaking-motion-our-fingertips) which says:

> The snapping of a finger was first depicted in ancient Greek art around 300 B.C. Today, that same snap initiates evil forces for the villain **Thanos in Marvel's latest "Avengers" movie**. That inspired a group of U.S. National Science Foundation-funded researchers at Georgia Tech to study the physics of a finger snap and determine how friction plays a critical role.

So the US government is on record as relating this research to Thanos and Marvel comics.

Georgia Tech, where some of the research took place, says in "[Oh, Snap!" A Record-Breaking Motion at Our Fingertips](https://research.gatech.edu/oh-snap-record-breaking-motion-our-fingertips):

> Acharya and Bhamla felt a particular push to apply this framework to a finger snap after seeing the movie Avengers: Infinity War, released in April 2018 and produced by Marvel Studios. In it, Thanos, a villainous character, seeks to obtain six special stones and place them into his metal gauntlet. After collecting them all, he snaps his fingers and triggers universe-wide consequences.
>
> ...would it be possible to snap at all while wearing an armor gauntlet, the researchers asked? In the case of a finger snap, they suspected that skin friction played a more important role compared to other spring and latch systems. With the frictional properties of a metal gauntlet, they imagined it might be impossible.
>
> ...
>
> “Our results suggest that Thanos could not have snapped because of his metal armored fingers,” said Acharya, first author of the study.

Comment: There is something unsatisfyingly incomplete -- not downvote-worthy -- about this answer. I could quote from the same sources to support the claim that this grant was about Greek art ("Based on ancient Greek art from 300 B.C., humans may very well have been snapping their fingers for hundreds of thousands of years before that") but it was a materials-research experiment ("investigations into ultrafast behaviors in animals") which only has a fun connection to Greek art in order to be approachable for laypeople.

Comment: This explains the Thanos connection, but falls to highlight the claim is a lie by omission.

Comment: @Corbin Georgia Tech is presenting the main research question as "would it be possible to snap at all while wearing an armor gauntlet?"

Comment: @Corbin I did find it downvote-worthy. The poster presents an article written in a "popular science" style, designed to attract the interest of and entertain laypeople, and perhaps inspire the younger ones to pursue a career in science, as giving the scientific justification for that line of research. Articles like this have little connection to the criteria scientists use when examining grant applications to see if they're worthwhile. It's not a good source to actually answer the question.